# Is navigation drawer fragments' xml file required in android studio 1.4?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am working on navigation drawer and have Android studio 1.4. I have read that in 1.4 we don't require fragment java files and can use " onNavigationItemSelected" in MainActivity file itself and trigger action on the basis of menu selected. Now my doubt is do i require the corresponding layout files for these menus and same task can be done in the header content xml file created by android studio itself??

Regards,
Navin

Comment: Just try and check if It is working or not and then post with code if not working..!!

Comment: @AndiGeeky I am yet to try this..just wanted to clear my doubt in which way should i move forward. If xml files for all the layouts can be avoided in AS 1.4??

Comment: Ideally you should update "Android Studio" ..!! :-p

Comment: Its already upgraded to 1.5 today and app doesn't run anymore on this windows 10 and android 1.5 combination :(

Comment: `Android Studio` is not working or `App` is not working ?

Comment: App not working...Emulator starts but application doesnt compile and it has happened after upgrading windows 8.1 to 10